# Put the data in a data structure (list, dict, etc.) In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataset, data-science

I don't even know where to start.

https://corgis-edu.github.io/corgis/datasets/python/electricity/electricity.py
https://corgis-edu.github.io/corgis/datasets/python/electricity/electricity.data

```
import electricity
utility = electricity.get_utility()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should considere to explain your problem before ask a question.
In anycase, I think you want to pass the information in electricity.data into a variable in Python, in order to do that you should use Pandas

```
pip install pandas
```

[Pandas Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html#user-guide)

Comment: I am having trouble reading and organizing the dataset into a matrix. right now it is in list form and I don't know how to turn it into a matrix.

Comment: with the columns : "number" "name" "state" "type"

Comment: You could read more carefully the Pandas documentation and how datasets works

Comment: From what I can see so far, it only talks about viewing. and when I try to use df.columns to try and view it, I get an error that "columns" is an invalid syntax or it cant be used because utility is in list format.